# Cannot log a JavaScript object to console, keep getting "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

So, I loaded up this object from my database in another view.js file:

```
exams : {
        "date" : [ 
            "01-21-20", 
            "01-22-20", 
            "01-23-20", 
            "01-24-20", 
            "01-25-20", 
            "01-26-20"
        ],
        "scores" : [ 
            3.3, 
            3.5, 
            2.9, 
            2.5, 
            3.6, 
            3.9
        ]
    }
```

The data was assigned to exams_var:

```
exports.getScores = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user && req.user._id) return res.redirect('login');

    const id= req.user._id;

    return Promise.all([ 
        db.findById('User', id)

    ])
    
    .then(resp => {

        console.log(id);

        const user_data=resp[0].doc;
        const exam_var= user_data.exams;
        console.log(exam_var);

        return res.render('views/scores', {
            title: 'Scores',
            scores: user_data.exams,

    });

    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    })


};
```

But when I try to do:

```
console.log(exam_var) it says "undefined".
```

Edit: Not yet solved. The "window" suggestion did not work, I get "window not defined".

Edit 2: Another user (@MadPapo) asked me to output user_data.
What is odd is that when I do

```
console.log(user_data)
```

it outputs ALL the database data just fine, INCLUDING the data I was trying to isolate and output specifically by itself, and it doesn't say "undefined".

When I try to do

```
console.log(exam_var)
```

it shows up as undefined. I can't specifically output that data by itself, which is the goal. Maybe I need to parse it??

Comment: try assigning it to `window.exams_var` Your exams_var is probably not in the global scope.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set that data to localStorage/sessionStorage and can get in the `temp.hbs` without any issue

Comment: I wish I could do that, but I get a local storage permission error, which is why I'm doing it the way I am doing. The biggest issue here is the second error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>)

Comment: @Tschallacka Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Tsachallacka That doesn't work. I get a "window is not defined" probably. Maybe it's because I'm using Node.js as well.

Comment: For node.js,  try `global.exams_var` for setting the global variable

Comment: That doesn't work either. For context purposes, I edited the post with the original code that I forgot to add initially...

Comment: You've defined `exams_var` as a `const` inside of the function passed to `then`. That is the only context in which that variable exists.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Excuse me for the noob questions because well...I am a total beginner at it. What should I have done? Because I see no solution. I've tried doing the same thing with other data and passed them to the hbs file in the same way, and they worked.

Comment: You should not edit "NOT SOLVED" into the title. Please stop doing that.

Comment: Sorry, I'll avoid doing that.

Comment: I have no idea where you're trying to access the data from. It appears you're passing the same data to 'views/scores' as `scores`? Maybe use that? I'm not familiar with handlebars, but if it's like most Node.js templating systems, that's how you pass data around.

Comment: I'm accessing the data that is in my MongoDb database and loaded the data in that function. When I do console.log(exam_var) to output the data from the object it doesn't output the data, it gives me "undefined". Forget about the handlebars thing for a sec, as it's probably irrelevant. The problem is I can't output the data in the console from that exports.getdata function, which is in plain javascript.

Comment: What is the output of console.log(user_data) ?

Comment: @MadPapo It outputs everything that is in the database. So it outputs the data I'm trying to access in addition to EVERYTHING else that is in the database (MongoDb). What's odd is that, I can't specifically isolate that data, exam_var, specifically and only output that.